# How do I add bullets to this script?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this script:

https://jsfiddle.net/4zuzxdxf/14/

CODE HTML:

```
<div id="slideshow">

       <ul>
           <li><img src="http://revistasindromes.com/images/100x100.gif" alt="photo1" /><p>asdas</p></li>
           <li><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100/4D99E0/ffffff.png&text=100x100" alt="photo2" /><p>ddd</p></li>
           <li><img src="http://www.matthijskamstra.nl/laboratory/flashbox/example_img/100x100pixels.gif" alt="photo3" /><p>eee</p></li>

       </ul>
        <a href="#" class="slideshow-prev">prev</a> 
        <a href="#" class="slideshow-next">next</a> 

    </div>
```

CODE JS:

```
   $('ul li').hide();
$('ul li:first').fadeIn();

 setInterval(function () {
                 $('.slideshow-next').click();
}, 6000);

var CurrentImage=0;

var AllImages=$('#slideshow ul li').length;

var NextImage=CurrentImage+1;

 $('.slideshow-next').click(function(){
      CurrentImage++;
     if(CurrentImage>=AllImages)
     {
         CurrentImage=0;
     }
     $('ul li').hide();
     $('ul li').eq(CurrentImage).fadeIn();

 });


 $('.slideshow-prev').click(function(){
      CurrentImage--;
     if(CurrentImage>=AllImages)
     {
         CurrentImage=0;
     }
     $('ul li').hide();
     $('ul li').eq(CurrentImage).fadeIn();

 });
```

CODE CSS:

```
#slideshow
{
    margin:0 auto;
    width:100px;
    height:150px;
}
ul{list-style:none;}
```

I want to add bullets for this script ... I added an image to better understand what they want.

http://i61.tinypic.com/717286.jpg

I have never done this and I need an example as simple.

Can you help me understand how to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try this jQuery plugin http://www.slidesjs.com/. Check "Example" section for more details.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few slider plugins out there.
But if you want to go purely `CSS` check out the following [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eaxz4jqx/1/)

I made the images slightly bigger, you can obviously change it as you want

***HTML***

```
<ul class="slides">
    <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-1" checked />
    <li class="slide-container">
        <div class="slide">
            <img src="http://revistasindromes.com/images/100x100.gif" />
        </div>
        <div class="nav">
            <label for="img-6" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
            <label for="img-2" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
        </div>
    </li>
    <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-2" />
    <li class="slide-container">
        <div class="slide">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100/4D99E0/ffffff.png&text=100x100" />
        </div>
        <div class="nav">
            <label for="img-1" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
            <label for="img-3" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
        </div>
    </li>
    <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-3" />
    <li class="slide-container">
        <div class="slide">
            <img src="http://www.matthijskamstra.nl/laboratory/flashbox/example_img/100x100pixels.gif" />
        </div>
        <div class="nav">
            <label for="img-2" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
            <label for="img-4" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-dots">
        <label for="img-1" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-1"></label>
        <label for="img-2" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-2"></label>
        <label for="img-3" class="nav-dot" id="img-dot-3"></label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

***CSS***

```
.slides {
    padding: 0;
    width: 609px;
    height: 420px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}
.slides * {
    user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}
.slides input {
    display: none;
}
.slide-container {
    display: block;
}
.slide {
    top: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 609px;
    height: 420px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    transform: scale(0);
    transition: all .7s ease-in-out;
}
.slide img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.nav label {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 9;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: opacity .2s;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 156pt;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 380px;
    font-family:"Varela Round", sans-serif;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgb(119, 119, 119);
}
.slide:hover + .nav label {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
.nav label:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
.nav .next {
    right: 0;
}
input:checked + .slide-container .slide {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}
input:checked + .slide-container .nav label {
    display: block;
}
.nav-dots {
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 9px;
    height: 11px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
}
.nav-dots .nav-dot {
    top: -5px;
    width: 11px;
    height: 11px;
    margin: 0 4px;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
.nav-dots .nav-dot:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
input#img-1:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-1, input#img-2:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-2, input#img-3:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-3, input#img-4:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-4, input#img-5:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-5, input#img-6:checked ~ .nav-dots label#img-dot-6 {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
```